# Why should ThreadPoolExecutor be used with Retrofit?

Tags: android, threadpoolexecutor, retrofit2

I saw android's ThreadPoolExecutor implementation with Retrofit somewhere. I am confused what is a logical need of using this executor with retrofit even if retrofit already provides us mechanism of asynchronous api calls, which will be run in different background threads without affecting other api calls?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, server is misconfigured and cannot manage simultaneous request. The server developper refuse to fix this problem on her side... For this reason, i add a ThreadPoolExecutor at Retrofit into my application for execute request one by one. Application use multiple Retrofit adapter, this library was not designed for that...